# Как обратиться к методу класса через итератор?

Tags: c++

Есть два класса, второй из них хранит в себе вектор, с указателями на объекты первого класса. Как во втором классе через итератор обращаться к методам обьектов первого класса?

В примере в `displayVectorINT()` и `displayVector()`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyFirstClass
{

public:
    int number;

public:
    MyFirstClass(int number_)
    {
        number = number_;
    }

    int returnNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

};

class MySecondClass
{

private:
    vector<MyFirstClass*> vec;

public:
    MySecondClass()
    {

    }

    void addToVector()
    {
        vec.push_back(new MyFirstClass(1));
    }

    void displayVector()
    {
        for (vector<MyFirstClass*>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << **it.number; //    <-- как обратиться к методу класса через итератор?
        }
    }

    void displayVectorINT()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << vec[i]->returnNumber(); // <-- тут работает
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    MySecondClass ob;
    ob.addToVector();
    ob.displayVector();

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью *(it)->метод.

`*(it)` разыменовывает итератор, а оператор `->` вызывает у указателя метод класса.

Comment: В первую очередь так и делал, но вот что говорит компилятор:
`error: request for member ‘returnNumber’ in ‘*(& it)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyFirstClass**, std::vector<MyFirstClass*> >::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘MyFirstClass*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)`

Comment: @havfsq вы заменили `**it.number;` на `(*it)->returnNumber();`? У меня компилируется без ошибок это

Comment: `(*it)->returnNumber();` - действительно работает, спасибо

Comment: `(*it)->метод`, а не `*(it)->метод`. Почему ответ с очевидной грубейшей ошибкой помечен как "принятый"?